# Call PHP Static Method using variable

Tags: php, class, static

I have various PHP classes (‘Numerical’, ‘Alphabetical’ etc.) under sub-namespace (‘MyNamespace’). I am trying to call this various classes under sub-namespace using php variable like

```
    class ClassName {
        public static function foo ($MethodName) {

            //$MethodName has value “Numerical”
            //Normal Way of calling ‘Numerical’
            MyNamespace\Numerical::MyFunction();

            //What I want to do
            $variable = ‘MyNamespace\$MethodName’;
                //OR
            $variable = “MyNamespace\$MethodName”;

            $variable::MyFunction();    //Option-1 - This does not work
            {$variable}::MyFunction();  //Option-2 - This does not work
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 7 you can use the following syntax:

```
$variable = "MyNamespace\\".$MethodName."::MyFunction";
$variable();
```

*Check [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ngiEk) to see the difference between PHP >= 7.0 and PHP < 7.0*

If you are not using PHP with a version of 7.0 or higher you cannot use this syntax. You can check the [documentation on variable functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) for more information.

Comment: Hi. I tried. The result is as follows:

  Validation\App::AppControl(); //This is working.

  $nameSpace = "Validation";
  $var = $nameSpace."\\App::AppControl";
  $var(); //This is not working. Error = Class 'Validation\App' not found

Comment: @Krishna That's because you forgot to put the required "\" before the namespace. `$nameSpace = "\Validation"` should work. It cannot find the class `Validation\App` because in your current namespace (the default one) there isn't a class `Validation\App`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `'` or `"` in code (about differences read http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single).

Check this out:
https://3v4l.org/cAk7W

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace {
    class Numerical {
        public static function MyFunction() {
            echo 'Called ', __FUNCTION__, '!', PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}

namespace AnotherNamespace {
    class ClassName {
        public static function foo($MethodName) {
            /**
             * Two backslashes because of \$ escapes to $ character and \\ escapes to «backslash» itself
             * @see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php
             * @see http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php
             * @see http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php
             */
            $variable = "\\MyNamespace\\${MethodName}"; // Option one works. 
            $variable::MyFunction();
        }

        public static function bar($className) {
            ('\MyNamespace\\' . $className)::MyFunction(); // Option two works in php version >= 7.1
        }
    }

    ClassName::foo('Numerical');
    ClassName::bar('Numerical');
}
```

Output for php 7.1.0 - 7.2.4:

```
Called MyFunction!
Called MyFunction!
```